# How to parse this JSON file using android library volley

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm building an android application but I'm not able to parse this JSON file, I am using volley android library.
JSON file link : https://api.covid19india.org/v4/min/data.min.json

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val recoveredT = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recoveredT)
    val url = "https://api.covid18india.org/v4/min/data.min.json"
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        {
            val x = it.getJSONObject("UT")
            val y = x.getJSONObject("total")
            z = y.getString("recovered")//I'm storing it in a variable z which is of type string. 
        },
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error in the hood boys!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    )
                 MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)

}
```

I'm trying to get info for "UT"

image :
[image]

Comment: What error are you seeing? The JSON at that URL verifies OK for me, so where is your problem?

Comment: @KenY-N I'm not getting any data in my variable z.

Comment: What about `x` and `y`? And where does `it` come from?

Comment: @KenY-N 'it' is the returned JSON object

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a **data class** from your **.json****

https://www.json2kotlin.com/

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-/

**2. Convert Your recived json to data class with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)**

**3. Add volley request to RequestQueue**

Example :

```
 val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        {
        val json = it
        val yourDataClass = Gson().fromJson(json, YourDataClass::class.java)
        val total = yourDataClass.UT.total

        }
    )

    RequestQueue  mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Finaly, You can use from your yourDataClass properties such as total

Comment: Can you please tell 2nd method in more details

Comment: I think you dont add your request to RequestQueue. I edit my answer and add third step.

Comment: with this snipet code , val yourDataClass = Gson().fromJson(json, YourDataClass::class.java) . I convert json to data class (step 2)